# xpath - assertTextPresent isn't finding the text in the UL, why not?

Tags: xpath, selenium, assert

If I have a list:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li><span class="A">Vans</span></li>
  <li><span class="B">Cars</span></li>
  <li><span class="B">Trucks</span></li>
  <li><span class="C">Vans</span></li>
  <li><span class="C">Cars</span></li>
  <li><span class="C">Trains</span></li>
  <li><span class="C">Cars</span></li>
  <li><span class="C">Bikes</span></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I check the last "Cars" item exists?

I am trying to use assertTextPresent

I am using `//ul//li//span[contains(text(),'Cars')][last()]` for the target, however this is selecting the **first** 'Cars' row as the span containing the text is inside the li

I also tried `//span[last()][contains(text(),'Cars')]` but this also select the first 'Cars' not the last.

I also tried `//span[contains(text(),'Cars')][last()]` but same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to find out if the text of the last `<li>` is "Cars", then:

```xml
//ul//li[last()][.="Cars"]
```

Testing using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org), which uses libxml2 (XPath 1.0):

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri.HTML('<html><head></head><body>
<ul>
  <li><span class="A">Vans</span></li>
  <li><span class="B">Cars</span></li>
  <li><span class="B">Trucks</span></li>
  <li><span class="C">Vans</span></li>
  <li><span class="C">Cars</span></li>
  <li><span class="C">Trains</span></li>
  <li><span class="C">Cars</span></li>
  <li><span class="C">Bikes</span></li>
</ul>
</body></html>')

puts doc.at_xpath('//ul//li[last()]')
#=> <li><span class="C">Bikes</span></li>

puts doc.at_xpath('//ul//li[last()][.="Cars"]')
#=> nil

puts doc.at_xpath('//ul//li[last()][.="Bikes"]')
#=> <li><span class="C">Bikes</span></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by "*the last "Cars" item*" you mean `<li><span class="C">Cars</span></li>`, you almost got it right.  You want `(//ul/li/span[contains(text(),'Cars')])[last()]`, which means "the last element in the set of elements that are `<span>`s containing "Cars" and contained within `<li>`s contained within `<ul>`s.